# Dynamically setting font-size using parameter in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

How to set font-size dynamically for all field in crystal report so that using one parameter user can change font-size of whole report ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for all fields / texts. See below:

```
aa = Report.Sections.Item("D").ReportObjects.Count
For i = 1 To aa
    Set crxFieldObject = Report.Sections.Item("D").ReportObjects.Item(i)
    bb = crxFieldObject.Name
    If Mid(bb, 1, 5) = "Field" Then
        cc = Val(Mid(bb, 6))
        For j = 1 To NumberOfFields 'your value
            If cc = xxxxx Then 'if your condition 
                crxFieldObject.suppress = False
                crxFieldObject.Left = Leftxxxx 'your value
                crxFieldObject.Top = Topxxxx 'your value
                crxFieldObject.Font.Size = Fontsizexxxx 'your value
                TenPointHeight = 221 'you can change this, too
                If crxFieldObject.Font.Size = 10 Then
                    crxFieldObject.Height = TenPointHeight
                Else
                    crxFieldObject.Height = TenPointHeight * crxFieldObject.Font.Size / 10
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```